# Error from navigation bar in React that appears only on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar like this:

Home About Contact Join

When the user logs in (with firebase) the "Contact" and "Join" page changes to "Rooms" and "Sign out". Now when running this react project on localhost everything works fine, after building the project I decided to host on firebase, now after deploying the page I opened it and saw that everything disappeared, not a single text or image, just the bg color that I set

[image]

and here is the console

[image]

**Error on line 3**

```
  const history = useHistory();
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth());
  const [stateWeb, setStateWeb] = useState(true); //// **Here is the ERROR, on this  line**
  return (
    <header className='header--nav'>
      <nav className='navigation--nav'>
        <img
          src={Logo}
          className='logo--nav'
          alt=''
          onClick={() => history.push("/")}
        />
        <ul
          className={
            stateWeb === true ? "list-ul--nav on--nav" : "list-ul--nav off--nav"
          }
        >
          <Link
            to='/'
            style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
            onClick={() => setStateWeb(!stateWeb)}
          >
            <li className='list--nav'>Home</li>
          </Link>

          <Link
            to={!user ? "/Contact" : "/join"}
            style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
            onClick={() => setStateWeb(!stateWeb)}
          >
            <li className='list--nav'>{!user ? "Contact" : "Rooms"}</li>
          </Link>
          <Link
            to='/About'
            style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
            onClick={() => setStateWeb(!stateWeb)}
          >
            <li className='list--nav'>About</li>
          </Link>
          <Link
            to='Join'
            style={{textDecoration: "none"}}
            onClick={() => {
              setStateWeb(!stateWeb);
              if (user) {
                history.push("/");
                auth().signOut();
              }
            }}
          >
            <li className='cta--nav'>{user ? "Sign Out" : "Join"}</li>
          </Link>
        </ul>
        <img
          src={menu}
          onClick={() => {
            console.clear();
            setStateWeb(!stateWeb);
            console.log(stateWeb);
          }}
          alt='test'
          className='menu--nav'
        />
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

**stateWeb** is a bool that tells if hamburger menu is open (on low resolution) so the navbar drops down

**Removing** the navigation bar entirely, resolves the problem!

Comment: I'm taking a guess, the error should be occurring in `useAuthState(auth());`, would you do that? `typeof auth === "function" ? auth() : auth`

I believe it'll mess up some functionality, but just to make sure that thing is what is actually crashing your app, or you can do a simple `console.log(typeof auth)` before this line is executed.

Comment: useAuthState(auth()) is for checking if the user is logged in or not, but I have an idea, I'll try it later and let you know thanks for your time!

Comment: Read the place that says `development build of Firebase SDK`

Comment: I don't know what problem are you seeing there, but as I said, if I remove the NavBar.js component everything works fine